# Receiving items emitted from an Observable

Tags: java, multithreading, rx-java, reactive-programming

Here's my code:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable.just("747", "737", "777")
        .flatMap(
            a -> {
              try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
              return Observable.just(a).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
            })
        .subscribe(p -> System.out.println("Received " + p + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));
  }
```

As I have understood it, each of the items of the observable should will run in a separate thread (which does happen) and the results would be sent to the same thread that did the work (this happens as well). But what I cannot understand is that why is the `main` thread not exiting and waiting for the background threads to finish? The program continues for as long as each of the background threads is running.

Comment: Try to check if there is any thread run in the background and increase the    `Thread.sleep(5000);` as well as reduce the  `sleep` in the background thread.

Comment: what happens when you add `.dispose()` after `.subscribe(...)` ? :)

Comment: @i_th the only background thread running is the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at a thread dump, you'll see that the `main` thread is actually stuck on the `sleep` statement. That's why it's not exiting.

This is because it is the thread that's executing the `flatMap` operator, so it's getting stuck. This also is why the code takes a long time to run. You can easily verify it by inserting a print statement just before `sleep`:

```
try {
  System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is sleeping");
  Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output is something like this:

```
main is sleeping
main is sleeping
Received 747 on thread RxNewThreadScheduler-1
main is sleeping
Received 737 on thread RxNewThreadScheduler-2
Received 777 on thread RxNewThreadScheduler-3
```

I think you've meant to write something like this:

```
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()  + " is creating the observable");
Observable.just("747", "737", "777")
        .flatMap(a ->
                 Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
                  try {
                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is sleeping");
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  return a;
                }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
      ).subscribe(p -> System.out.println("Received " + p + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));
System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " is going to exit");
```

Output:

```
main is creating the observable
main is going to exit
RxNewThreadScheduler-3 is sleeping
RxNewThreadScheduler-2 is sleeping
RxNewThreadScheduler-1 is sleeping
Received 777 on thread RxNewThreadScheduler-3
Received 747 on thread RxNewThreadScheduler-1
Received 737 on thread RxNewThreadScheduler-1
```

In this version `main` is exiting right after the Observable is created.